# How to introduce a Type-Parameter for Array Length in Rust?

Tags: arrays, generics, rust

I have a little question concerning generics in Rust. I want to make the length of an Array a type parameter.

**Question: Does Rust currently support that?** 
The error message does not indicate a missing feature but a programming error.

Example of what I want to do:

```
fn create_array<C: ConstSize>(){
    let arr = [64; C::SIZE];
    println!("array.len: {:?}", arr.len());
}

pub trait ConstSize {
    const SIZE: usize;
}
```

with some example implementation:

```
fn main() {
    create_array::<Five>();
}

struct Five {}
impl ConstSize for Five {
    const SIZE: usize = 5;
}
```

But the compiler tells me:
`no associated item named 'SIZE' found for type 'C' in the current scope`

However, the following works:

```
fn create_array(){
    let arr = [64; Five::SIZE];
    println!("array.len: {:?}", arr.len());
}
```

[**See the example on the Rust Playground**](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0d74d539c9fb75e6ecf8ecd2276412f7&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug. There is related issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52070

Comment: This answers my question. You could write that into a separate answer.

Comment: The difference is quite subtle: The linked question asks how to solve that problem in general, with the answer being a future feature of Rust, but the specific solution in this question should actually work right now (but it's a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated constants can not be used to specify the length of an array  due to a compiler bug ([issue #52070](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52070)).